# Does Any Version Of Py2Exe Support MySQLdb Module?

Tags: python, mysql-python, py2exe

I am using `Py2Exe` to convert `Python` into `.exe` file.
Now I have installed MySQLdb module into `Python 2.7`.

Can `Py2exe` still convert my `Python` script which contains MySQL connection into Exe file?

Answer (score 0):

I am using py2exe and python2.7 and compiled my exe without problem. The only thing that needs  to be specified on the setup file the MySQLdb module.

Here is my sample setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=[{"script" : "main.py"}], options={"packages":["MySQLdb",]}})
```

Comment: Hi @Modge I'm just answering the original poster. Python2.7 compiled the MySQLdb without an issue you just need to specify the package otherwise py2exe will generated exe file will give an error   `ImportError: No module named MySQLdb` during runtime